# Excel External Workbook Reference

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that needs to reference a closed or open (closed preferable) external workbook to transfer cell values over.

The External Workbook is in:

**C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Folder1**

and it is called **"Page.xls"**

My Code:

```
dim tmpCell as range
set tmpCell = Sheet3.("A1")

tmpCell.Value = '... Dunno what to put right here
```

The space behind the equal sign is where I want to put my externally referenced workbook/cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try:

```
tmpcell.formula = "='C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Folder1\[Page.xls]Sheet1'!A1"
```

If this does work, then best case scenario you will still have problems if you ever move or mess with that source workbook, and even if you don't I think Excel still has a tendency to behave strangely referencing other workbooks like that.

Your other options would be to (first make sure the source workbook is closed) open the workbook, copy the values over, and close it:

```
dim tmpCell as range
set tmpCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")

dim sourceWorkbook as Workbook
set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Folder1\Page.xls")
dim sourceWorksheet as Worksheet
set sourceWorksheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

tmpCell.Value = sourceWorksheet.range("A1").Value

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
sourceWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

The last option would be to do an ODBC connection to the workbook - I do like this second option though

Answer (score 0):

I've never found a way to access a closed Excel file. The following is what you need to open a file, copy a value, and close the file.

```
dim tmpCell as range
set tmpCell = Sheet3.("A1")
set myFile = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Folder1\page.xls"
set myFileName = "page"
set mySheetName = "Sheet1"
set myRange = "A1"

workbooks.open fileName:=myFile
tmpCell.Value = Workbooks(myFileName).Sheets(mySheetName).range(myRange).value
workbooks.close fileName:=myFile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:

```
tmpCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='C:\path\[workbook.xls]Sheet1'R1C2"

'Or alternatively:
tmpCell.Formula = "='C:\path\[workbook.xls]Sheet1'B1"
```

Read more about that [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e861b34e-3161-4497-a17b-6d20732d1e74/hyperlink-in-excel-from-vba-macro)